# The source contains no DataRows using Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have multiple Data Table and filter with first Data Table with second Data Table and same as third Data Table using first Data Table email.

Below is my C# code:

```
  public void getexport()
{

    DateTime Fromdate = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_FromDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    DateTime Todate = DateTime.ParseExact(txt_ToDate.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    bo.Dateused = Fromdate;
    bo.Dateused2 = Todate;
    var ds = new DataSet();

    var dt = new DataTable("Registration Details");
    DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Education Details");
    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Employeement Details");


    dt = bl.Get_Registrationdetailsbydate(bo);
    gv_Regdetails.DataSource = dt;
    gv_Regdetails.DataBind();
    dt1 = bl.Get_Educationdetailsbydate(bo);
    dt2 = bl.Get_Employmentdetailsbydate(bo);

    Session["Fromdate"] = txt_FromDate.Text;
    Session["Todate"] = txt_ToDate.Text;
    if (gv_Regdetails.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

            DataTable filteredEducation = dt1.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
          .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim())).CopyToDataTable();

            DataTable filteredEmployee = dt2.AsEnumerable()
         .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
          .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>  ("Email").Trim())).CopyToDataTable();

            dt.TableName = "Registration Details";
            filteredEducation.TableName = "Education Details";
            filteredEmployee.TableName = "Employeement Details";

            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            ds.Tables.Add(filteredEducation);
            ds.Tables.Add(filteredEmployee);
            ExcelHelper.ToExcel(ds, "DangoteUsers.xls", Page.Response);
            btnExport.Visible = true;



       }
  }
```

I am getting error in filteredEducation and filteredEmployee Datatable, when there is no DataRows.

```
DataTable filteredEducation = dt1.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim())).CopyToDataTable();

DataTable filteredEmployee = dt2.AsEnumerable()
   .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
  .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim())).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem come here because you are trying to CopyToDataTable when you don't have any records. So solution will be

```
var firstDataTable = dt1.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim()));

DataTable filteredEducation  = new DataTable();

if(firstDataTable.Any())
{
    filteredEducation  = firstDataTable.CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var row = dt1.AsEnumerable()
  .Where(x => dt.AsEnumerable()
 .Any(z => z.Field<string>("Email").Trim() == x.Field<string>("Email").Trim())).ToList();//Add ToList() at the end of this query.

DataTable filteredEducation  = row.Any() ? row.CopyToDataTable() : filteredEducation.Clone();
```